# Reading a remote image file

Tags: silverlight, filesystems

My problem seems simple, but for some reason, I can't quite seem to fix it.
I need to set an image, in silverlight, based on a remote image file.
I am aware, that Silverlight can not read the clients filesystem, but what about the servers filesystem? Or another remote shared filesystem?

How do I get it to read a .png file, that is stored in a public location, and set my Image control to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<Image Source="http://example.com/image.png" />
```

You should also be able to set the `Source` in the C# code as well via the following code:

```
BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://example.com/image.png", UriKind.Absolute));
image.Source = bmi;
```

This assumes that you have permission to read the image at that location.

Comment: When I try to set Source from code, it doesn't accept a string path. Instead, it wants a BitmapImage, and setting that's URISource, doesn't really seem to work for me.